# Fixing broken pipe error in uWSGI with Python

Tags: python, rest, timeout, wsgi, uwsgi

While hitting a REST resource (`my_resource`) in Python, the uWSGI server is throwing the following error in its log:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request my_resource (ip <my_ip>) !!!
uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 164]
IOError: write error
```

It seems to be related to a timeout (the client disconnected before the request could finish processing).

What sort of timeout is this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it depends on your frontend server. For example nginx has the uwsgi_read_timeout parameter. (generally set to 60 seconds). The uWSGI http router as the --http-timeout default to 60 seconds and so on. As you are talking about a rest api i am quite doubtful it requires more than 60 seconds to generate a response, are you sure you do not have some wrong response header triggering a connection close by the frontend webserver ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.  There are particular reasons why this single request takes longer to generate a response, which we will deal with when necessary.  For now, however, incrementing the timeout seems to be the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem and could not solve it this way.
Im using Flask and i expect request being a bit bigger since they bring audio binary data with variable duration between 2secs and 15secs. Even with small audio samples traveling in the request i keep getting thisi message in the error log.

Comment: the issue i had was fixed upgrading openssl version 1.0.2g

Answer (score 9):

if you are using the `uwsgi` nginx plugin, consider using

```
uwsgi_connect_timeout 180;
uwsgi_read_timeout 180;
uwsgi_send_timeout 180;
```

Comment: In which file to add these values?

Comment: inside nginx.conf

Answer (score 1):

The StackOverflow answer here helped me [uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768527/uwsgi-ioerror-write-error#:%7E:text=%23%20when%20a%20client%20closes%20the%20connection%20then%20keep%20the%20channel%20to%20uwsgi%20open.%20Otherwise%20uwsgi%20throws%20an%20IOError%0A%20%20%20%20uwsgi_ignore_client_abort%20on%3B)

42 upvotes:

The problem is that clients abort the connection and then Nginx closes the connection without telling uwsgi to abort. Then when uwsgi comes back with the result the socket is already closed. Nginx writes a 499 error in the log and uwsgi throws a IOError.

The non optimal solution is to tell Nginx not to close the socket and wait for uwsgi to come back with a response.

Put uwsgi_ignore_client_abort in your nginx.config.

```
location @app {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;

    # when a client closes the connection then keep the channel to uwsgi open. Otherwise uwsgi throws an IOError
    uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
}
```

It is not clear if it is possible to tell Nginx to close the uwsgi connection. There is another SO questin about this issues: (Propagate http abort/close from nginx to uwsgi / Django)

Yuda Prawira
David Dehghan