# How can I filter out errors on sentry to avoid consuming my quota?

Tags: django, filter, client, uwsgi, sentry

I'm using Sentry to log my errors, but there are errors I'm not able to fix (or could not be fixed by me) like

**OSError (write error)**

[image]

Or error that come from **RQ** (each time I deploy my app)

[image]

Or **client errors** (which are `client.errors`)

[image]

I can't just ignore them because I consume all my quota. How I can filter out this errors?

Here some references for interested people.

- [uwsgi: OSError: write error during GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026602/uwsgi-oserror-write-error-during-get-request)
- [Fixing broken pipe error in uWSGI with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133315/fixing-broken-pipe-error-in-uwsgi-with-python)
- https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1623

Answer (score 1):

To safe yourself some quota, you have two options:

1. **Avoid forwarding events client side**, thus preventing events being send to sentry at all. Have a look at the [docs for available client-side filters](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/filtering/). The drawback with this approach is of course that you need a new code deployment for any adjustment of client-side filters and some clients may not instantly reflect your code changes.
2. **Avoid forwarding events on sentry's side**, via [inbound filters](https://docs.sentry.io/product/data-management-settings/filtering/) (`[Project] > Project Settings > Inbound Filters`). According to the sentry documentation on quota usage, events filtered via inbound filters are [not affecting your quota](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/#inbound-data-filters).

Inbound filters include:

- Common browser extension errors
- Events coming from localhost
- Known legacy browsers errors
- Known web crawlers
- By their error message
- From specific release versions of your code
- From certain IP addresses

Business plans and above also allow to filter events by error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Gist for rate limiting the amount of events that are being send to Sentry:

https://gist.github.com/jurrian/e22f8e724b8499a29c5537e956f0dc7f

It uses [ratelimitingfilter](https://github.com/wkeeling/ratelimitingfilter) which can be configured to set a rate per minute, and additionally add a burst to start rate limiting after a number of events.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same errors, but i never had any problems with my quota. But if you really want to filter it, you can just do it in your sdk:

https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/filtering/?platform=python

But beware, this could hide other errors as mentioned here: 
https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/679