# What does this UWSGI error mean? " SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd "

Tags: uwsgi, sigpipe

There are a few questions related to this issue, but none of them actually help me understand what is going on.

The full error:

```
 SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request
```

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133315/fixing-broken-pipe-error-in-uwsgi-with-python)，i think u are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply means that the client, i.e. the sites visitors, closed their connection. 
Either by closing the browser, or through a connection error on their part.

Comment: I got the same errors for django app, but the user didn't close the page. As a matter of fact the page didn't display at all and the errors only occurred when the page's bigger than a certain size (80000 bytes to be specific).